# How to get featured image of post from wordpress in ionic?

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework

How to get a featured image of post from WordPress in ionic? URL I'm using for fetching data from WordPress:

```
 var wordpressUrl = "http://ionicwordpress.tantraxx.com/wp-json/posts?filter[category_name]=shows";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the "featured_image" from that json and you should get the link from the image.

In case of error, check if you have the correct options in wp-json plugin.

Comment: for display title we use post.title what i can use for display featured image